# Saving an array of images to parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, parse-platform

I have an `array` of images in a `UIImage` `array` and I'm looking to save this to parse. I know how to save a regular image to `Swift` but how do I send multiple images that are all related to each other.

Basically I have a mosaic app that takes an image and beaks it down into 30 smaller images. How can I save those 30 images together to parse with text and other fields as well.

Comment: Save an array of images as Data (NSData)?

Comment: How would I do that, can you show me

Comment: Your question is not much specific, though, Just try to convert to UIImage to NSData type then save those data, later you can convert that.

Comment: Look it up.  I'm not the first to save an array as Data.  Not even the second or 10th...  Besides, I don't even know your Swift version.

Answer (score 0):

convert image to data

```
 let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
```

convert data to image

```
let image = UIImage.init(data: imageData)
```

**Updated**

```
let imagArr = [UIImage.init(named: "a.jpg"),UIImage.init(named: "b.jpg"),UIImage.init(named: "c.jpg")]
        let dataArr = NSMutableArray()
        for eachImage in imagArr{
            dataArr.add(UIImagePNGRepresentation(eachImage!)! as Data)
        }
```

let me know is it helpful or not

Comment: I have a UIImagearray, how do I save that

Comment: There is no data type such as UIImagearray, Are you saying there is an array which contains all yours images? If it is then iterate or use a for loop.

Comment: Yes there is an array that holds all my images. Can you show me an example of that

Comment: What do you think

Comment: Can you show me how I would save it

Comment: And how I would fetch the data

Comment: Could you please show me that

Comment: Showing me how to save and retrieve this array of images From a classname, etc

Comment: Are you talking about to save it in local disk?

Comment: No saving and fetching it from parse

Comment: Do you know how to do it

Comment: could you please comment and tell me what you think

Comment: Are you using any api to save and fetch ?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. Would you know how to do it

Comment: I'm using the parse frameworks for my parse server. And this is the only problem I have left

Answer (score 0):

compress image if size is big or leave, convert image to to data and data to base64string .. save string to parst ..
on return .. convert base64 string to data and data to image ..

This would be efficient i guess .. i am doing this for iCloud s
synchronization

Comment: Can you show me how I would do this in parse

Comment: -(NSString *)converImageToBase64:(UIImage *)image
{
    return [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
 base64EncodedStringWithOptions:
NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
}

Comment: the above method will convert the UIImage to Base64String

Comment: now to convert Basse64 to UIImage
 NSData *imageDataB64 = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:yourB64String                                                                                                        options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
                                                if (imageDataB64)
                                                {
                                                    UIImage *profileImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageDataB64];

Comment: Could u make an edit above to show me how to convert the uiimagearray to a string and how to retrieve it

Comment: I'm having a hard time following it in the message

Comment: What do you think is faster. Saving 150 images as jpegs in .75 quality or converting 150 images to string data and saving that data to parse and reconverting it when I try to fetch it into a tableview

Comment: it will take less time then uploading and downloading 150 images

Comment: create a string array from image array by converting each image to string, by using NSMutable Array

Comment: it will reduce the time on network communication